# JQuery if is visible doesnt work with parent-child?

Tags: jquery

I have a parent DIV (.box) and a child (#display). I would like fade out the parent if the child is hidden. But it still doenst work :S

```
if( $('#display').is(':visible') ) {
     $(this).parent(".box").fadeTo(100,1);
} else {
     $(this).parent(".box").fadeTo(100,0.7);
}
```

Comment: still doesnt work... maybe because there are more than one .box divs?

Comment: You should post more code *around* this, when is it being called?

Comment: If there's more than one `.box`, then does that mean there's more than one `#display` as well? If so, you're using invalid HTML because you can not use the same ID attribute more than once on a page. Please post more code, both javascript and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what advice to give, since I don't know what is triggering this code.

I'll assume this is not in an event handler.

```
var $display = $('#display');  // cache #display for better performance

if( $display.is(':visible') ) {
     $display.parent(".box").fadeTo(100,1);
} else {
     $display.parent(".box").fadeTo(100,0.7);
}
```

The value of `this` will reference the element receiving an event inside its event handler. This does not work the same for `if()` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not using `$(this)` correctly. Try changing your code to:

```
if( $('#display').is(':visible') ) {
     $('#display').parent(".box").fadeTo(100,1);
} else {
     $('#display').parent(".box").fadeTo(100,0.7);
}
```

You can read more about the `this` keyword [in ppk's site](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

Answer (score 0):

Reinis' code should work, if not try this:

```
if( $('#display')[0].is(':visible') ) {
     $('#display')[0].parent().fadeTo(100,1);
} else {
     $('#display')[0].parent().fadeTo(100,0.7);
}
```

Also, make sure you're firing this code. Try putting some alerts in there to be sure.

Comment: DOM elements don't have these methods...this would result in several errors  :)

Comment: These are jQuery wrapper methods that we're using here. If the jQuery library is there, it'll not give any errors, hopefully :).